# How to connect SQL Server 2008 R2 to PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using XAMPP locally as my server for the project and database, I need one MySQL database (locally) to save data but I need to connect to another database (on the same network) to get the registred users, this database is on a SQL Server 2008 R2 Server.

How can I connect my project with the Server? Do I need an special configuration on XAMPP? I have checked the PHP documentation but It is not working :(

```
$serverName = "(MyIP\USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS)";  
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => "data", "PWD" => "somepass",    "Database"=>"databasename");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  

if( $conn )  
{  
 echo "Connection established.\n";  
}  
else  
{  
  //It always end up here
  echo "Connection could not be established.\n";  
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
}
```

Comment: What OS are you using and what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, I needed to instal the ODBC on my computer and the dll in the PHP folder for XAMPP